# Redis hgetall or hget?

Tags: redis

There is redis hash with 100-200 fields. If I need take 2 or 3 values, what method is best way?

First way is call hgetall, but i got many useless data.

Second way is call hget key1, hget key2 and hgetkey3 - but is three different call.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do not use [`HGETALL`](https://redis.io/commands/hgetall) unless you need the entire Hash's contents (beware, however, of its O(N) time complexity).

You can use the [`HMGET`](https://redis.io/commands/hmget) command to retrieve only those fields in the Hash that are of interest to you.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the deprecation [here](https://redis.io/commands/hmget)

Comment: i think this answer not correct, the HGET - single filed and return a single value, HMGET - multiplier fields and return an array. Testing on 6.0.5:

redis> HGET Name n1 n2
ERR wrong number of arguments for 'HGET' command

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HMGET`: https://redis.io/commands/hmget

```
HMGET myhash field1 field2 nofield
```

Testing on 6.0.5:

```sh
# even 1 field, return an array
redis> HMGET Names n1 
0
name1

redis> HGET Names n1
name1

# Cannot accept multiple fields for HGET
redis> HGET Names n1 n2
ERR wrong number of arguments for 'HGET' command

redis> HMGET Names n1 n2
0
name1
1
name2
```

Comment: Similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47072575/9962007 ;)