# What is the explanation of the Redis HGETALL time complexity

Tags: redis

The time complexity of the `HGETALL` command is [according to the documentation](https://redis.io/commands/hgetall/) O(N) where N is the size of the hash. In many cases where `HGETALL` is mentioned, users are often warned about its time complexity for example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47072575/1924825) without going much into what `HGETALL` does under the hood and why the time complexity is the way it is. So why is this O(N)? Has it something to do with how Redis stores the hashes, is it networking, or is it just CPU-bound? `HGET` has the [time complexity of O(1)](https://redis.io/commands/hget/) and is not dependent on size in any way, so can I just store my hash set as one value concatenated with some separator to improve performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redis stores a Hash as a hash table in memory. Getting a single entry from any hash table, by its very nature, is an O(1) operation. HGETALL has to get all of the entries in the hash table, one by one. So, it's O(N). If you coded your own hash table and didn't use Redis, it would also work that way. This is just how hash tables work.

Serializing your hash table to a single string and then saving that string will not save you anything. You're replacing an O(N) operation on the backend for one in your code.

The thing I always find missing around discussions of time-complexity is that it's about scaling, not time. People talk about things being "slower" and "faster". But it's not about milliseconds. An O(1) operation is "constant time" not slower. That just means it always takes the same amount of time—every time. A function can be O(1) and still be slower than some other function that is O(N) with a billion entries.

In the case of Redis, HGETALL is really fast **and** O(N). Unless you have thousands of fields in your Hash, you probably don't need to worry about it.

Comment: just out of curiosity, although I understand there is no set measurement with generalization we can make, what's the rough idea of time it takes for this call when item is in thousands?  would still be dominated by network latency if we are using Redis service provided by cloud companies such as AWS or Azure?  Or the O(N) is large enough it more likely dominates over even network latency?

Comment: I think it would still be dominated by network latency. The bigger risk is that the core of Redis is single-threaded and so, under heavy load, the act of retrieving lots of fields with a call to HGETALL prevents other requests from being processed. This is the same reason be discourage the use of KEYS. HSCAN can mitagte this for Hashes in the same way that SCAN can mitigate it for KEYS.